# How to save data to db using laravel import?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have prepared code below, and I'm using the `dump` to trace if it passed to models' `create` function.

When I checked in the database there is no data added, I'm just wondering why it does not have when it is already passed in `User::create` function (verified by string "created" below in the picture).

---

These are the dump datas returned *(note: i'm using picture for better visualization)*

[image]

---

And here is my code in **UserImport.php**

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    User::create([
        'name' => $row[0],
        'birthdate' => $row[1],
        'gender' => $row[2],
    ]);

    dump('created');
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        '1' => ['required'],
        '2' => ['required'],
    ];
}
```

And about dumping the validations message is my **UserController** *(to shorten, i will just post the important parts)*

```
catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e)
{
    $failures = $e->failures();
    dd($failures);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Laravel Excel uses database transactions to ensure data integrity when performing imports. You have failures, so the entire transaction was rolled back.

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#database-transactions

> #Database transactions
> The entire import is automatically wrapped in a database transaction, that means that every error will rollback the entire import. When using batch inserts, only the current batch will be rollbacked.

Comment: thanks for the direct answer sir. I know its out of the scope of the question, I would like to ask, is there any way we could implement like this, **"save data, then if it fails to specific row, stop"**?

Comment: Possibly, though it would require some customization. And disabling transactions is not advisable. I would probably lean toward the simpler solution which would be to skip over invalid rows. This could be handled by removing the built in Laravel Excel validation and simply checking whether those values are satisfactory within the `model()` method before calling `User::create()`. But you would have to handle the error reporting if you want to know what was skipped.